# Sort list of double array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, dictionary, collections

I have this dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, List<double[]>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<double[]>>();
```

I filled it with a lot of data.

each array in the list has two values like this:

```
[xvalue, yvalue]
```

Is there anyway so I can sort each list in the dictionary depending on the `xvalue` of the arrays.

#### For example

This is the list

```
[[1,100], [10, 100], ....[3, 100]]
```

#### After sorting should be this

```
[[1,100], [3,100], [10,100]]
```

To be honest, All I did is google searching for such a feature but I couldn't do more than that because I am not that good in c# and I thought asking you would save a lot of time.

Comment: If you arrays always have two elements, you should really go for a `Tuple<double, double>` (or your own type) instead of an array.

Comment: And if you go for that option, you may even prefer to make the `List` 1-dimensional by storing first and second elements of the Tuple in sequence in the `List`. So for example [1,5][2,8][3,4] will become [1,5,2,8,3,4].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over all element of the dictionary and sort each of the lists. You can sort a list by calling `List.Sort` with a proper comparison function.

```
foreach(var entry in dictionary) {
    entry.Value.Sort((a, b) => a[0].CompareTo(b[0]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answering, but maybe you did something wrong ? I got `can't convert lamda expression to doubt[]` in the `a,b` part of your answer

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: Please try again. I fixed some errors and made it shorter.

Comment: it seems you were the first guy answering me :) thanks will accept

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
foreach (var pair in dictionary) 
{
    pair.Value.Sort((x, y) => x[0].CompareTo(y[0]));
}
```

Comment: you are amazing . thanks a lot. it works. +1. will accept once the system allows

Comment: @Marco Dinatsoli, thanks, but think about accepting Danvil's answer. He was first :)

Comment: @2kay okay will do that

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
dictionary = dictionary
             .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
                           x => x.Value.OrderBy(a => a[0]).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be to iterate through the keys. Access each list under specific key. Sort each list and replace the unsorted list with the new sorted one:

```
foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys)
{
    dictionary[key] = dictionary[key].OrderBy(i => i[0]).ToList();
}
```